# IOS IAP succeed but does not charge the user

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

Recently pubished an app to apple store (couple of hours ago). The in app purchase goes through showing a success message. However, it does not ask for payment information nor charge the user. This is the purchase flow:

1. user clicks on the product
2. apple storekit shows a message with pricing and purchase option
3. apple asks for sign in inof to complete the purchase
4. apple shows a successfull purchase message

In Sandbox mode, the same flow happens, however, it says you will not be charged as you are in sandbox mode.

In production, it just doesnt charge the user.

the product is approved in app store connect

The IAP code is:

```
import Foundation
import StoreKit

public struct InAppPurchasesCallbacks {
    var onFetchCompleted: (([SKProduct]) -> Void)?
    var onProductsNotFound: (([String]?) -> Void)?
    var onPurchaseSucceeded: ((SKProduct, SKPaymentTransaction) -> Void)?
    var onPurchaseFailed: ((SKProduct, Error?) -> Void)?
    var onRestoreCompleted: (([SKPaymentTransaction]) -> Void)?
    var onRestoreFailed: ((Error?) -> Void)?
    
    public init(onFetchCompleted: (([SKProduct]) -> Void)? = nil, onProductsNotFound: (([String]?) -> Void)? = nil, onPurchaseSucceeded: ((SKProduct, SKPaymentTransaction) -> Void)? = nil, onPurchaseFailed: ((SKProduct, Error?) -> Void)? = nil, onRestoreCompleted: (([SKPaymentTransaction]) -> Void)? = nil, onRestoreFailed: ( (Error?) -> Void)? = nil) {
        self.onFetchCompleted = onFetchCompleted
        self.onProductsNotFound = onProductsNotFound
        self.onPurchaseSucceeded = onPurchaseSucceeded
        self.onPurchaseFailed = onPurchaseFailed
        self.onRestoreCompleted = onRestoreCompleted
        self.onRestoreFailed = onRestoreFailed
    }
}

public class InAppPurchaseWrapper: NSObject, SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver {
    private var products = [SKProduct]()
    private var callbacks: InAppPurchasesCallbacks
    private var productIdentifiers: Set<String>
    
    public init(productIdentifiers: Set<String>, callbacks: InAppPurchasesCallbacks) {
        self.productIdentifiers = productIdentifiers
        self.callbacks = callbacks
        super.init()
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
        fetchProductInfo()
    }
    
    private func fetchProductInfo() {
        let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIdentifiers)
        request.delegate = self
        request.start()
    }
    
    public func purchaseProduct(_ product: SKProduct) {
        let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)
    }
    
    public func restorePurchases() {
        SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
    }
    
    private func validateTransaction(transaction: SKPaymentTransaction, product: SKProduct) {
       // some backend server verification calls, removed for security here.
    }
}

// MARK: - Delegate methods
extension InAppPurchaseWrapper {
    
    public func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
        products = response.products
        let unrecognized = response.invalidProductIdentifiers
        
        if products.count == 0 {
            if unrecognized.count > 0 {
                callbacks.onProductsNotFound?(unrecognized)
            } else {
                callbacks.onProductsNotFound?(nil)
            }
        } else {
            callbacks.onFetchCompleted?(products)
            
            if unrecognized.count > 0{
                callbacks.onProductsNotFound?(unrecognized)
            }
        }
    }
    
    public func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        for transaction in transactions {
            switch transaction.transactionState {
            case .purchasing:
                break
            case .purchased:
                let product = products.first {
                    $0.productIdentifier == transaction.payment.productIdentifier
                }
                
                if let p = product {
                    validateTransaction(transaction: transaction, product: p)
                    callbacks.onPurchaseSucceeded?(p, transaction)
                } else {
                    callbacks.onProductsNotFound?(nil)
                    queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
                }
            case .failed:
                let product = products.first {
                    $0.productIdentifier == transaction.payment.productIdentifier
                }
                
                if let p = product, let e = transaction.error {
                    callbacks.onPurchaseFailed?(p, e)
                } else {
                    callbacks.onProductsNotFound?(nil)
                }
                queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
            case .restored:
                let product = products.first {
                    $0.productIdentifier == transaction.original?.payment.productIdentifier
                }
                if let p = product {
                    callbacks.onPurchaseSucceeded?(p, transaction)
                } else {
                    callbacks.onProductsNotFound?(nil)
                }
                queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
            case .deferred:
                break
            @unknown default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
    
    public func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError error: Error) {
        callbacks.onRestoreFailed?(error)
    }
    
    public func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue) {
        callbacks.onRestoreCompleted?(queue.transactions)
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't call `finishTransaction` in the successful path of the `.purchased` case. The user isn't charged until you finish the transaction. Even though you aren't actually charged in development or TestFlight modes, you should still get the chime and payment vibration feedback. If you don't get that then you aren't completing the transaction successfully. If you aren't targeting earlier than iOS 15 consider using storekit2. It is much simpler.

Comment: Any pending transactions will still be in the queue and they will be presented again (this is why registering a transaction observer should be one of the first things your app does on launch). You should also always call `finishTransaction` before actually providing the IAP, otherwise you could end up delivering the purchase more than once for a single purchase.

Comment: Finally, you would not expect to see the user be asked for payment information; the purchase is just billed to their payment method in their apple account.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, there was a 5-hour delay in charging the customer from Apple's side. not sure if this was due to being a new app, or that is always the case. However, all purchases went through after about 5 hours.